# How to scale up/down all resources in a Azure subscription using Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

We would need to scale up multiple resources hosted in a Azure subscription on need basis and scale them down later. Do we need to go the ARM way or the Powershell/Azure CLI way? We are using Azure DevOps for CI/CD and any insights into this would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Why not configure autoscale rules?

Comment: In our case, we want to update all the resources in one shot and down grade them.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, ARM would be prioritized fit for your requirement because it fits in the requirements like deploy, manage, monitor many of the resources for a solution as a group rather than handling multiple resources individually. For more information with regards to this, I would suggest you to read through all the comments and conversation that has happened in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463106/azure-provisioning-with-jenkins) Stack Overflow thread which includes [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2015/12/18/understanding-azure-provisioning/) and [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/product-categories/management-tools/) tutorial references that confirms the same that ARM is the prioritized fit for requirement like yours.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!